# Is the sentence 'I don't know' a Proposition?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am confused among three sentences that are they propositions or not?

i) 'I don't know', in my view this sentence is a Proposition, because it's truth value can either be `true` or `false`. Also it can be expressed in Propositional logic as below:

$$\begin{array}{l}Let\\p = I~know\\\therefore \\ \sim p = I~dont~know\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGceaqabeaacaWGmb
% GaamyzaiaadshaaeaacaWGWbGaeyypa0JaamysaiaadUgacaWGUbGa
% am4BaiaadEhaaeaacqGH0icxaeaacqWI8iIocaWGWbGaeyypa0Jaam
% ysaiaadsgacaWGVbGaamOBaiaadshacaWGRbGaamOBaiaad+gacaWG
% 3baaaaa!4C1B!
$$

ii) 'God is One', this sentence varies according to atheists and mono-atheists, so for poly-atheist, this sentence holds both `true` and `false` values.

iii) If 'God is One' sentence can be a Proposition, then '*`x + 1 = 8`*' could be a Proposition as well. Because, we know if `x` is equal to `7` then it hold the truth value 'true' otherwise it holds the truth value 'false'.

So kindly anyone explain me in details that are all of these 3 sentences Propositions or not? Explain if not and also explain if they are.

Comment: What has this to do with mathematics? Answer: nothing. Conclusion: vote to close.

Comment: This is the Propositional Calculus question, if you know about it, it is the branch of Mathematics.

Comment: Propositional logic deals with **uninterpreted** propositions. The interpretation of natural language statements like "God is One" is outside the scope of mathematics. And so your question is outside the scope of MSE. Is that enough "details" for you?

Comment: In your third example, it depends on quantification of the declaration.:"$\forall x( x+1=8)$" is patently false. "$\exists x(x+1=8)$" is true.

Comment: @RobArthan The definition of proposition has the word `declarative sentence`, now it can be of any language, it does not need to be only a Mathematical Expression containing symbols. So my question is clearly not out of the scope.

Comment: What definition of proposition? Your question is way outside the scope of MSE.

Comment: What is MSE? What does it stand for?

Comment: Math StackExchange?

Comment: Well done! You've just noticed the name of the forum whose time you are wasting.

Comment: @RobArthan we can express the English sentences (which have either true or false value) in Propositional Logic using hat (^), vel (v) and negation (~). So if I am not understanding these statements and I have asked here then how am I wasting the time? Well, then you recommend me the place where should I ask this, if this is not the right place?

Comment: You didn't give enough context! See my response to your last comment on Bram28's answer. But the bottom line is unchanged: "God is One" is not a mathematical proposition and cannot be analysed mathematically.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would say they are indeed all propositions ... but in all cases we are missing important information to figure out exactly what is being claimed, let alone figure out their truth-value.

'I don't know' -> *what* is it that you claim that you don't know?

'God is One' -> what does that even *mean*?

'x+1 = 8' -> what $x$ are you referring to?

But I can also see how someone can argue that because we don't know the exact nature of the claim, they are actually not propositions.

Comment: So, what should we do in the case if we do not know the exact nature of the term? Should we call such sentence a Proposition or not?

Comment: Also, `x > 2x` in this sentence, it holds the truth value 'true' for all values of x, so x does not need to be bound to something else. So, can we say without any worry that, it is a Proposition?

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar Again, I can see arguments being made either way ... Personally, I would call all of them Propositions ... They certainly have the right 'format'. That is, something like 'God' by itself is clearly *not* a proposition, but just a term, and something like '>' is just a predicate, so that is also clearly not. Proposition. But with 'God is One', at least it combines a termp with a prdicate, so even though I have no idea what is meant by it, I do consider it a claim or Proposition ... But I would call it a very vague claim. How does your book define a Proposition?

Comment: I really think it is stretching it to consider the asker's expressions as propositions.  Since we can't see inside the head of one who claims "I don't know", and expressions of faith/belief can't be said to be true or false.  If one declared, "according to the religion X, abcdefg," that can be judged true or false independently. And clearly you address that arguments can me made to conclude the expressions are not propositions.  I think my comments are answered with respect to "propositions" as they are defined in logic.

Comment: @amWhy Yeah, I can go either way ...

Comment: @Bram28  And I do understand your answer; and you make a good point.

Comment: @amWhy I guess I have just done too much formal logic ... If I hear 'sburgs are flib', then I think $\forall x (Sburg(x) \rightarrow Flib(x))$, which I see as a perfectly good Proposition, even if I don't know what it means.  It's my 'syntactical bias' I suppose! :)

Comment: @Bram28: your "syntactical bias" should encourage you to detect cases like "God is One" accompanied by blather about its actual truth value based on religious points of view..

Comment: @Bram28 So if I consider 'God is One' as ∀x(God(x)→One(x)) then it would be a perfect Proposition?

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar I would probably do that one as $One(God)$

Comment: @RobArthan i am not asking the question in accordance of religious views. I just stated that atheists, mono-atheists and poly-atheists have different views about that One statement, so that as the definition of Proposition states `The declarative sentence is the Proposition, if either it is true or false but not both`, then if we look "God is One' sentence has both true and false values according to three types of beliefs, so it can't be a Proposition, right?

Comment: @Bram28 great, so _**One(God)**_ would be proposition?

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar: no that is not right. "God is One" has no truth value in mathematics.

Comment: Well, leave the second and third sentences, but is the first sentence '`I don't know`' a Proposition? I know the views of the speaker of this statement must be known that for what did he/she say 'I don't know'. But if we are in a case that we don't know the reason behind this sentence, then what would be the most suitable say, it is a Proposition, or it is not a Proposition?

Comment: @Bram28: this has nothing to do with mathematics and you shouldn't be encouraging a debate that is irrelevant to MSE.

Comment: @RobArthan Well, I was asked this question (the question about `I don't know`) in my university in the Mathematics Class after the lecture about "What are Statements/Propositions and Compound Statements". I was not sure about the answer so I just simply said that I don't know. So now you tell me that if this is not a Mathematics question, then why was I asked this question in my class?

Comment: Perhaps to make you think! You should have given this information about the context in your question? (In which case I would have excoriated your teachers rather than your question.)